# Bash: Skip to next step in loop if `curl` failed to connect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I have a bash script which goes through a list of IP addresses and tries to `curl` information from them. However, sometimes a server cannot to contacted (`curl: (28) Failed to connect to XX.XX.XXX.XX port YYYY: Connection timed out`) and my script endups trying infinitely to reach him. How can I change my code, to ensure that if I run into such failed connection my bash script will just go to the next IP on the list? I tired with some `if-else` statement and `continue` but this didn't work.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
filename='ips.txt'
n=1
while read line;
do
# reading each line
echo "Line No. $n : $line"
curl https://someaddress | jq -r '.[].foo.value' | xargs -I % curl http://$line:YYYY/foo -o $line.json
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  continue
fi
n=$((n+1))
echo -en "$i        \r"
done < $filename
```

Comment: Which curl's failure do you want to handle? The first one in the pipeline, or the one in `xargs`?

Comment: In your code: No matter what your `if` condition is doing, you will continue with the next iteration of the loop, i.e. the next line. The only difference is that *when* xargs returns a non-zero exit code , you do not increment the variable `n` (which does not have any influence to the logic of your script anyway).  Honestly, I don't quite understand the logic behind your script. Maybe it would give you some insight if you put a `set -x` on the top of the script and analyze the output...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

filename='ips.txt'
n=1

while read line;
do

  # reading each line
  echo "Line No. $n : $line"
  
  curl https://someaddress | jq -r '.[].foo.value' | xargs -I % curl http://$line:YYYY/foo -o $line.json
  
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "Download failed! Try again with next IP..."
  else
    n=$((n+1))
    echo -en "$i        \r"
  fi
  
done < $filename
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but sadly didn't work. The same thing happened with the problematic server.